# How to use WSL to develop Angular project in Dropbox directory?

Tags: angular, permissions, dropbox, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I tried to develop Angular app using WSL, with the project in a Dropbox folder.
I get the following error :

```
my-user:/mnt/c/Users/me/Dropbox/Angular$ ng new my-app
? Would you like to add Angular routing? No
? Which stylesheet format would you like to use? CSS
EACCES: permission denied, open '/mnt/c/Users/me/Dropbox/Angular/my-app/README.md'
```

I installed WSL, with the last LTS Ubuntu version (18.04 LTS on March 2020) : https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/windows/wsl/install-win10
I installed node :

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo -E bash - sudo && sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Then I installed Angular :

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@8.0.1
```

The project creation (ng new my-app) works if I do it outside of the Dropbox.

Why are there permission problems with the dropbox and how to solve them ?

Comment: What does it say if you sudo it?

Comment: Well same thing happens with Onedrive. Make you a favor and don't use your source code in a Dropbox folder

Comment: I have the same result using "sudo", and starting Ubuntu as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you have windows file/folder permissions on the dropbox folder. Try in an admin console. or ensure that the folder does not require special security or belong to a different user.

Comment: I have the same result using "sudo", and starting Ubuntu as administrator. The rights are 777 (RWX for all users). Really strange behavior ... :/